# smart casting for doing a safe cast

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin 1.2.50
```

I am doing a smart cast and just wondering if this is the correct way to do it. As `params.bottomMargin` is highlight by the code editor to be `Smart cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams`

```
    val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
    val params = child.layoutParams
    if(params is RecyclerView.LayoutParams) {
        val dividerTop = child.bottom + params.bottomMargin
        val dividerBottom = dividerTop + drawable.intrinsicHeight

        drawable.setBounds(dividerLeft, dividerTop, dividerRight, dividerBottom)
        drawable.draw(c)
    }
```

Just wondering if there is something I can do more with the above code to cast `params to RecyclerView.LayouParams`

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: This looks perfectly fine!

Comment: What do you mean by `if there is something I can do more with the above code to cast params to RecyclerView.LayouParams`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct usage of smart casts. If you want an alternative, you can also use the `when` statement or a safe cast, like these examples:

```
when (params) {
    is RecyclerView.LayoutParams -> { /* smart cast here */ }
    else -> { /* optional other cases */ }
}

// casts to RecyclerView.LayoutParams? and then invokes the body of let if not null (when params is a RecyclerView.LayoutParams)
(params as? RecyclerView.LayoutParams)?.let {
     /* smart cast here */
}
```